# What sound samples haven't been recorded?

Tags: sampling, field-recording, library

In the world of online sample packs, some sounds are far too easy to find (read: overload of the same thing in many sample packs). This may be dog barks, running water, etc. What I have found is that some samples are quite rare, and as such draw a lot of attention.

What sound samples are missing from the spectrum of sample packs out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *so many* unrecorded sounds...and even a lot of recorded sounds that aren't available for purchase. That's why most of us love what we do, right?

But in the spirit of answering your question, I'd like to see more collections based on scientific recordings (geological processes, outer space recordings, etc.). They're out there, often public domain, but hard to pull together or find, and some of the most interesting ones are packaged as acoustic ecology recordings rather than discrete samples. (Not a criticism, some of them make for totally amazing listening!)

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad everything can't be recorded!  I'd be out of a job!

There are so many different ways to record something, and so many different ways to make a sound - so many infinite variables...

Although it would be nice to have access to a library of sounds that are less accessible or not practical to record (say, sounds 1 mile deep in the ocean, or outer space recordings that Nathan mentioned.)

That's what keeps it interesting!  I'm not a huge fan of libraries anyways.  Truly organic and original sound is what, in my mind, separates the boring from the tantalizing (although something is to be said for the quick and easy library sound in a pinch or a tight deadline...)

Answer (score 1):

sound is infinite!

Answer (score 0):

Normaly when samples are missing, I create it or record it. So i don't think I realy need something.

But sometimes i just need more movements from the same sound (for exemple; a car) or more channels 5.1...